# Cancel "Close" operation

Tags: feature-request

We required an option to cancel "Close" operation. This will help peoples who voted for closing a question by mistake.

Comment: For now: just add a comment saying that you clicked 'close' by mistake, and asking the next person who wants to close to leave a comment instead saying he's used your vote. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Of course, if they feel so strongly about closing, I doubt they will *not* use their own close votes. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been declined at [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) (the master meta), although the decision to do so was not popular.